# MSI message 1610 on uninstall

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, uninstallation

I have a setup created with InstallShield 2015 Basic MSI project.
When running the uninstall I get a message box and this in the MSI log file:

```
  MSI (s) (4C:78) [18:17:52:182]: RESTART MANAGER: Detected that application with id 4, friendly name 'System', of type RmCritical and status 1 holds file[s] in use.
  MSI (s) (4C:78) [18:17:52:182]: RESTART MANAGER: Did detect that a critical application holds file[s] in use, so a reboot will be necessary.
  MSI (s) (4C:78) [18:17:52:182]: Note: 1: 1610
```

At the first step I want to understand why I get this message rather than avoiding it.

How can I know which files\services are the trigger for it.
( I already checked this registry key and it was empty )

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\FileRenameOperations
```

Comment: It tells you why you get the message - the System process is using a file that is going to be changed (deleted?) by the uninstall. If you need more detail then post the entire log it might name the file. Also, the System process typically won't use the files from a typical user install, so perhaps you're installed a file that belongs to the OS. That key is actually called PendingFileRenameOperations

Comment: Hi, I looked at the MSI file but couldn’t find any clue on which file cause this issue but I will try to upload it. I also checked PendingFileRenameOperations in registry and it’s empty. What I also don’t understand is I get the mentioned message why don’t I get the FileInUse dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

The System process is using a file that is going to be changed (deleted?) by the uninstall. If you need more detail then look at an entire verbose log because it might name the file - you may see entries with error 1603 referring to in-use files. Also, the System process typically won't use the files from a normal user install, so perhaps you're installed a file that belongs to the OS. The System process hosts a lot of drivers, so if you have any .sys files then that's likely to be a candidate.

That key is actually called PendingFileRenameOperations, but you may not see anything there because there isn't a pending rename. If this is an attempt to remove a file that's in use by the System process then it's not a rename. Removal at reboot uses a different process for MSI-based post reboot actions.

The FilesInUse dialog is shown only if the process that is holding the files open can be shut down. You can't shut down the System process so it won't show FilesInUse.